# Is "I am sat" bad English?

Tags: grammaticality

Is "I am sat" bad English? I believe it is incorrect and instead either the present continuous

> I am sitting

or the predicate adjective

> I am seated

should be used.

I hear this quite often, however, and ultimately usage overrules formality.  Does anybody know where this originated or how to describe it grammatically?

Comment: It's northern Englandish.  I get told off for using it by my southern wife...

Comment: Strangely enough, even as an American, it sounds normal to me. I quite frequently say *be sat*. To me it's just like *be gone*, expressing a state rather than an action.

Comment: @Jon I have seen that particularly in the context of it referring to something someone does *to* you; i.e. "I was seated by the hostess." Also, when referring to positioning; "I am seated by the purple pipe organ." (U.S.)

Comment: @mfg: It's not exactly the same. *The waiter seated me, whereupon I found myself sat in the back of the smoky Italian restaurant with nothing to do* is fine. *The waiter sat me* is just wrong, and if *the waiter sat me down* then I'd expect him to give me a stern talking-to for some reason. Probably for failing to smoke in what is obviously a smoking-mandatory establishment, I dunno.

Comment: @Jon I think we agree? I just meant that in "I was seated by the hostess" or "the hostess seated me", either case, usage of I/me is as an object, and indicates a state into which the object was interred by the subject (hostess). This does not necessarily require some dependent clause, just as "My mom laid me down" doesn't.

Comment: "The waiter sat me" is an idiomatic phrase (a participle participating previously in bad grammar), typically followed with something like "...down to cuss at me about smoking in the cafeteria of the Oncology wing."

Comment: @mfg: Alright, yeah, agreed. I just wanted to clarify. I think the phrase/al verb is really *to sit (sb) down*, though. It sounds harsh, if not outright wrong, without *down* or similar.

Comment: I was out with my coworkers last night and *they sat us* in the quiet section of the restaurant.

Comment: This should be closed for lack of research.\

Comment: In my Midwestern American, "I am sat somewhere" is acceptable as a passive of "someone causes me to sit somewhere", and could be used in reporting a dream in which someone has me sit in some particular place.  So "sat" is a past participle.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Forms like "I am sat here" and "they were stood there" are common in certain dialects of English (such as Yorkshire, where I live), but are not regarded as standard English, which prefers "I am sitting here" and "they were standing there".

They are examples of stative verbs, which in many languages have a different grammar from other verbs, but exactly how the form arises I don't know. [Edit: also, they *don't* pattern with the class of verbs usually called "stative" in English, in that they do have continuous forms: "I am sitting" etc.]

Comment: Interesting. I don't think it's at all common in America. The Google hits I can identify geographically all seem to be UK. It's standard enough (or hip enough) for [Hive magazine](http://www.hivemag.com/interview-blood-red-shoes/), apparently.

Comment: I think you are correct in point one, however, after reading your answer I have been learning about stative verbs and I do not agree that *sit* is one because if this were the case, then the form *I am sitting* would be invalid.  An example of a stative verb is *know*, where the form *I am knowing* is invalid. http://esl.about.com/od/grammarstructures/a/g_stative.htm

Comment: You're right that they don't pattern with the class of verbs called "stative" in English; but semantically they certainly are stative, and in some languages have particular grammar because of that. But it was probably unhelpful for me to call them "stative" here. I was trying to capture a property of these words and no others that I can think of in (some dialects of) English.

Comment: @z7sg - Are you sure "I am knowing" is always invalid?  An old girlfriend used to call me a "knowing f***-it-all", and I thought she had a valid point.

Comment: @MT_Head Yes, she probably did.

Comment: @MT_Head: @z7sg is correct.  You've placed the article outside the quotes in your example, but it's quite necessary to said usage.

Comment: I knew as I was typing it that I should have added "LOL" or "<g>" at the end.  I thought it would be obvious from the content that I was joking, but one should never assume these things.

Comment: @MT_Head: "I am knowing" is possible using the adjective "knowing" (though it is rather an unlikely thing to say of oneself). But not with the continuous verbal form.

Comment: There has been a revisiting of this topic; can you please supply relevant support for your statements in paragraph 1?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Im not sure which part you want supported, but the OED s.v. _sit_ , 18.b, says " In pa. pple. with _is_, _was_, etc. Cf. _to sit down_ 1 at Phrasal verbs 1   (b). Now _dial._", and GloWbE has 1769 instances of "(be) sat", from GB, and 830 from everywhere else put together.

Comment: Thank you. This reinforces the duplicity of a recent question.

Answer (score 10):

Some notes on all this from the *OED*...

The transitive verb [***to seat***](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/174374) meaning “to cause to sit down” is first cited in 1623’s *Henry VIII*. [***Seated***](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/174377)   meaning “sitting down” is an adjective derived from the transitive verb ***to seat***, and whose earliest citation in English is from Scott in 1817.

The simple past and the past participle of [the **much** older verb ***to sit***](http://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/180462) are both simply  ***sat***, and nothing more. Its  reflexive and transitive senses, respectively meaning “to seat oneself” and “to cause someone to be seated”, date from time immemorial. Some relevant citations for the “I am sat” sort of sense include:

- The Middle English work *Cursor Mundi* has “þe folk ware satte” [“the folk were sat”].
- A 1711 citation that includes “The Court was sat”.
- An 1803 citation of “Where‥Hermon and his friend were sate.”

It is interesting to note that the older *sate* spelling includes several 19<sup>th</sup> citations, including Thackeray’s *Vanity Fair* of 1848.

I can in summary find no hint of condemnation in the *OED* for the use “I am sat”. However, these entries have not been updated since the Second Edition of 1989, and it is possible that more recent hypothetical opprobrium for such things has not yet found its way into being reflected there.

Answer (score 7):

> [1] i. *<sup>?</sup>I am sat*
> ii. *I am sitting*
> iii. *I am seated*
>
> (? denotes questionable grammaticality)

In [1ii], the **gerund-participle** *sitting* is just a simple verb -- indicating that the subject is sitting.

In [1iii] we have the **past participle** used in what *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* calls the **ascriptive** use of ***be*** (a kind of **copular clause**).

[1i] sounds wrong. Is it wrong? No. It's just not standard usage.

> In the ascriptive use, PC [predicative complement] denotes a property and characteristically has the form of AdjP or … NP.

That is, an ascriptive copular clause takes the form *NP + **be** + AdjP* (or *+ NP*, but we definitely don’t have an NP here). A verb can be inflected to be used as an adjective by using the gerund-participle form or the past participle form. *Sat* is the past participle of *sit* and thus, unless I’m missing something, [1i] must be grammatical.

This, of course, does not apply when the preterite and past participle are not syncretised.
Consider the following:

[2] **I am want* [preterite]
ii. *I am wanting* [gerund-participle]
iii. *I am wanted* [past participle]

[2i] is ungrammatical, while [2ii] and [2iii] are fine.

In summary, *I am sat* is an example of the ascriptive use of ***be***.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that *sat* is the past participle of *sit*.  If it isn't, then I don't know what is.

Comment: What makes you say it's the past participle of sit? It is the simple past form of sit. I'm sure we can agree that "took" is the simple past form of "take", while "taken" is the past participle. Another use of the past participle is for the perfect: "I have taken him a long letter" and "I have seated myself down" while "I have took myself down" doesn't work, nor does "I have sat myself down".

Comment: Although, after running a quick Google search, it looks as though I may be wrong. Let me do some more research. :) Yes. I am wrong (OED says so!). Now that I have had my embarrassing moment and have learnt such a simple verb as "sit", I can update my answer.

Comment: Hehe we all have these moments from time to time. :)

Comment: Haha. True. Hopefully I've given a reason that it is grammatical now though (far from what I thought I was showing).

Comment: OK, so admittedly I don't fully understand this answer but as far as I can tell it is a correct and thorough explanation.

Comment: I must not have explained myself very well, which is a failure on my part. Can anyone make my answer easier to understand?

Comment: Example [2] is wrong -- the preterite of *want* is *wanted*. Try *chose/choosing/chosen*.

Comment: Also, this still seems to say that the past participle of *sit* is *seated*. I agree with z7sg that it's *sat*.

Comment: "I am want" may sound valid to some, but this is because it sounds like the correct construction "I am wont".

Comment: I'd maybe put "%" rather than "?". In dialects where these forms are used, they're not particularly of 'questionable grammaticality' from a descriptive point of view.

Answer (score 2):

I would accept all of

- The cat sits on the mat
- The cat is sitting on the mat
- The cat sat on the mat
- The cat has sat on the mat
- The cat was sitting on the mat

but also the transitive or passive forms of *seat* and *sit*

- She seats the cat on the mat
- She sits the cat on the mat
- She seated the cat on the mat
- She sat the cat on the mat
- She has seated the cat on the mat
- She has sat the cat on the mat
- The cat was seated on the mat by her
- The cat was sat on the mat by her
- The cat has been seated on the mat
- The cat has been sat on the mat
- The cat was seated on the mat
- The cat is seated on the mat

That only leaves

- The cat was sat on the mat
- The cat is sat on the mat

which I find difficult to reject, though here *sat* has a passive tone to me.

Comment: "She sat the cat on the mat." is a transcription error, originally "She set the cat on the mat."  (Wonder if the rhyming makes the error more common?)

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Would you regard "She sits the cat on the mat" as a transcription error? This kind of phrase is common enough: for example "she sat him down in the lady's lap" appears Dickens' *Sketches by Boz*;  "she sits him down and administers the necessary aid" in Kerouac's *The town and the city*

Comment: I would say that either *She seats him* or *She sets him down* (depending on whether he moves under his power or hers) would be better.  The past forms irk me much more, I'd never use *has sat* transitively, and the passive constructions *was sat*, or *has been sat* just don't work IMO.  Note that you have *was sat* in two of your lists.

Comment: "She sat the cat on the mat" is certainly not a transcription error. In my dialect (and I think in most British ones), it is _far_ more natural than your form with "set", as "set" is not an everyday word for "put" or "place".

Answer (score 1):

Colloquially, "I am sat here" or "I am sat there" carries with it a sense that someone has done it to you. As in the construct "She sat me down and told me ...". It's typically used when telling a story or complaining. You wouldn't use it for a circumstance like being at your desk working or at home watching TV under normal conditions. You might use it for being in a doctor's waiting room, or outside the principals office. I suppose if you felt trapped at work (or even at home) and strongly wanted to be somewhere else, you might: "She's in the hospital, and I'm sat here with nothing to do, but no way to get to her and keep her company."

Comment: Well I wouldn't, but the usage that caused me to ask the question was in exactly that circumstance. :)

Comment: No, it does not carry that sense in those dialects where the phrase is common.

Comment: @Colin who are you disagreeing with?

Comment: Yes. This construction is known as the *antipassive*.

Comment: But I admit that it does often carry a sense of annoyance.

Comment: @Kate: I was disagreeing with you, that it does not for me carry a sense that somebody has necessarily done it to you. On an afterthought, I realised that if often does have a sense of annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

The unresolved question is whether or not it is acceptable to say I am/was sat/stood **intransitively.**  more generally <>.  As a southern UK speaker I hear this construction more and more frequently and I am puzzled by it.  I would use the verb to-have in these cases e.g. I have sat/stood, I had sat/stood or use the continuous e.g. I am/was standing/sitting.  When I hear *"I am sat here"* or *"I am stood there”* etc. I wonder "by who", i.e. I take it to be transitive.

Colin Fine above says *"Forms like "I am sat here" and "they were stood there" are common in certain dialects of English (such as Yorkshire, where I live), but are not regarded as standard English, which prefers "I am sitting here" and "they were standing there".*  If so we note "I am/was sat/stood" = "I am/was sitting/standing" not "I have/had sat/stood".  So a Northerner would say “I was stood at the bus stop when you drove  past” meaning “I was standing at the bus stop when you drove  past”;  but would  not “I was I was stood at the bus stop but then I walked home” meaning “I stood at the bus stop but then I walked home”

In such Northern dialects what verbs  **other**  than **to sit** and **to stand**  use the past/past participle in lieu of the gerund (verb-ing).  E.g. would you *say I am/was ran/left/bought/swam* instead of *I am/was running/leaving/buying /swimming?* and if not why not? What is the rule?

Comment: On further reflection, verbs e.g.  to run, to hate, to hurt, to wound, to kill, to sit, to seat, to stand, to fly, to grow, to know can have (i)  a present participle e.g. running (ii) a simple past e.g. I hated,  (iii) a past participle which is often the same as the simple past e.g. run, but sometimes different e.g. flown.

The past participle is used with  to be and to have.  

When used with to have the case is active. Thus if we say I have run,  it is I who ran.

When used with to be the case is passive,   So with I am hated,  I do not hate, but it is me  is hated.

Comment: Verbs e.g.  to run, to hate, to hurt, to wound, to kill, to sit, to seat, to stand, to fly, to grow, to know can have (i)  a present participle e.g. running (ii) a simple past e.g. I hated,  (iii) a past participle which is often the same as the simple past e.g. run, but sometimes different e.g. flown.

The past participle can be used with both  **to be** and **to have**

With "to have" the case is active, with to be the case is passive.   To be consistent  "I am/was sat/stood " would be passive, like "I am/was hated,hurt"  not not active like "I am/was sitting/standing hating, hurting".

Answer (score 1):

Etymonline has to sit, Proto-Germanic *setjan and to set, Proto-Germanic *satjan. Very similar. Perhaps that in some northern dialects the distinction between to sit and to set was given up. Influence of Norsk?
Old Norse for to sit is sitja, for to set setja. Sitja and setja might easily  have been muddled into one verb in northern dialects. But such a question would be the task for dialect specialists.

Comment: I have always suppoosed that _set_ is a causative of _sit_, as _fell_ is of _fall_ and _raise_ of _rise_.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that, though extremely awkward, it would be correct, as *sat* is the past part of sit.  Seat is a similar verb that means "to sit down."

Side note: *sit* may be transitive or intransitive, but *seat* is always transitive and must take a direct object.

Comment: Can you give an example of transitive "sit"?  I think it's used when either "seat" or "set" is meant.

Comment: *Sit yourself down, and I'll bring you some coffee.* -from NOAD

Comment: I'd argue that is at least awkward, possibly incorrect.  Either *sit down* or *seat yourself* would be better.  But maybe that's just my tendency to exclude extra words that add nothing to the sentence's meaning.

Comment: I'm afraid you are not arguing with me but with the authors of the New Oxford American Dictionary.  Feel free to take it up with them.

Comment: @BenVoigt See the OED’s [sit](http://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/180462), which contains numerous citations of *sit* used transitively and reflexively, uses dating from time immemorial up through and including the present day.

Answer (score -1):

> All those verbs which do not admit of being combined with the
>   substantive verb, are called *intransitive* or *neuter* : such as,
>   *sit*, *stand*, *lie*, *sleep*, &c. We can say, I am trained, loved, watched, &c. ; but we do not say, **I am *sat***, *stood*, *slept*, &c.-**The etymologic interpreter; or, An explanatory and pronouncing dictionary of the English language** (1824)