# Grammatically correct use of 'whilst stood'

Tags: grammar

Is 'whilst stood in a cable car' correct grammar or should it be 'whilst standing in a cable car'?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6/when-did-while-and-whilst-become-interchangeable and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18609/is-i-am-sat-bad-english?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using 'sat' and 'stood' as adjectives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/176972/using-sat-and-stood-as-adjectives)

Comment: "Stood" as well as "standing" is a verb. They are both non-finite clauses functioning as complements of the prep "whilst". The PPs are probably functioning as supplementary adjuncts in some larger construction. Semantically, there is little real difference between the two.

Comment: Don't bother using _whilst_. It's rare and dialectal at best; there's no reason for a superlative suffix on _while_.